# WooCommerce additional information are coming hapazartly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written a plugin which insert data into the database like WooCommerce but the products additional information like size are not coming with any order, I do not know form where it is fetching and how it is fetching. the results like below

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you add a "0" to the front of your single-digit numbers, that will straighten it out.  It is currently putting it in number order by first number, which is correct.

Example:
 0, 04, 06, 08, 10, etc.